# What kinds of materials are useful for field emission vacuum tube cathodes?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, electronics

I've read that graphene has been used for small scale field emission but what about on a much larger scale? For example what are the "cold cathodes" of FEM miscroscopes made up of?

Comment: Tungsten is a common cold cathode emitter material. (Tungsten is also commonly used for thermionic emission as well).

Comment: What about Lanthanum Hexaboride?